# firebase.collection.doc.get Is running multiple times

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can I prevent my document query from being run constantly. I want to retrieve the document value only once. In my code I have this. When the user tries typing in the form it is running the following code block and preventing updates to the form.

```
var docRef = store.collection('users').doc(props.route.params.user.id)

  docRef.get().then((doc) => {
    if (doc.exists) {
      setInterests(doc.data().interests);
      setAbout(doc.data().about);
    }
  });
```

For example this form isn't updating because of the query.

```
<TextInput
          multiline
          numberOfLines={3}
          placeholder="About Me"
          placeholderTextColor="#666666"
          value={about}
          onChangeText={setAbout}
          style={[styles.textInput, {height: 90}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using functional component, the **minimal code** to run any code **only once** when component mount is as follows

```
useEffect(() => {

       var docRef = store.collection('users').doc(props.route.params.user.id)
    
      docRef.get().then((doc) => {
        if (doc.exists) {
          setInterests(doc.data().interests);
          setAbout(doc.data().about);
        }
      });

},[])
```

> If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and
> unmount), you can pass an empty array ([]) as a second argument. This
> tells React that your effect doesn’t depend on any values from props
> or state, so it never needs to re-run. This isn’t handled as a special
> case — it follows directly from how the dependencies array always
> works.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

#### In case you don't know what is useEffect

> If you’re familiar with React class lifecycle methods, you can think
> of useEffect Hook as **componentDidMount**, **componentDidUpdate**, and
> **componentWillUnmount** combined.

Comment: useEffect allows code to be run multiple times NOT once. This worked but I don't understand why.

Comment: you need to add the empty dependency represented by an empty array `[]` so it will run only once. I believe I quoted the explanation of the empty array in my answer.

Comment: Yeah but it's just normal function code. useEffect is when you need to asynchronously re-run stuff. I just need this call to run once. Do you know if this is a react or firebase issue? It seems like it should call the query once by default.

Comment: @chackerian , if you want to run stuff once when component loads, you need to use `useEffect(() => //dosomething , [])` If you don't put the code inside useEffect, then it will be run whenever the page renders

Comment: I thought the page just renders once

Comment: everytime u call `onChangeText` the page re-rerenderrs since u call `setAbout` that changes state